# Weighted mean or average including negative numbers

Tags: statistics, computational-mathematics, average

Let's say I have have multiple values: `[12, 8, -6, 0, -1]` with weights `[20%, 20%, 30%, 15%, 15%]`, how could I calculate its weighted average or mean?

Is it possible we can calculate weighted average or mean including negative numbers? Thanks.

For arithmetic mean, its quite simple for the array:

```
(12 + 8 - 6 + 0 - 1)/5 = 13/5 = 2.6
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764795/weighted-average-with-a-negative-number

Comment: Well, you'd need to have weights.  Beyond that, why do you imagine that the sign(s) of the numbers matters?

Comment: Is it possible weights be negative?

Comment: It would be unusual, but there's no reason why you couldn't compute the sum-product, $\sum w_i\times a_i$.  You would need to ensure that $\sum w_i\neq 0$ of course.

Comment: I suppose a better question would be:  what do you intend to use this computation for?  That motivation should guide your definition.

Comment: I need to calculate score for an item based on multiple factors effecting it, some factors have positive effect, but others have negative.

Comment: Well, that's pretty vague.  Note that if $\sum w_i$ is a small number, then your formal score might be gigantic even if each individual term is small.   I suggest writing out some explicit examples to decide what sort of metric suits your needs.

Comment: Usually each weight will be positive, or at least non-negative with a positive sum.  There is no problem using those to weight values which can be a mixture of positive, negative and zero

Comment: I've manually set weights (sum of weights is 1) for the array, but at this case, the result seems not weight mean/average, which is calculated by `12*0.2 + 8*0.2 - 6*0.3 +0*0.15 -1*0.15 = 2.05`.

Comment: The result of what?   If the weights, $\{w_i\}$ are all positive then the weighted average of the data $\{a_i\}$ is the sum product $\sum w_i\times a_i$ divided by the sum of the weights $\sum w_i$. i mean, that's the definition.  What other computation are you doing?

Comment: You mean the weighted mean of `[12, 8, -6, 0, -1]` with weights `[20%, 20%, 30%, 15%, 15%]` is `2.05`?

Comment: @ahbon Yes, your calculation of $2,05$ is correct. As long as the _weights_ are nonnegative and sum to $1$ (as your percentages do) it does not matter what the values are. They may be negative. You can post that as an answer to your own question and accept it, so it does not stay on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of @Ethan Bolker, since the sum of weights is $1$, the weighted mean of $$[12, 8, -6, 0, -1]$$ with weights $$[20\%, 20\%, 30\%, 15\%, 15\%]$$ can be calculated by:

$$12*0.2 \,+\, 8*0.2 \,-\, 6*0.3 \,+\, 0*0.15 \,-\, 1*0.15 \,=\, 2.05$$